# Prestashop: problem with logo, I don't see it in front end

Tags: php, prestashop

website: www.e-veloce.com

I don't see logo.

I tried to change src in header.tpl to

```
<a href="{$base_dir}" title="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
<img class="logo img-responsive" src="https://www.e-veloce.com/presta/img/logo.jpg" alt="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{if $logo_image_width} width="{$logo_image_width}"{/if}{if $logo_image_height} height="{$logo_image_height}"{/if}/>
</a>
```

after that, I don't see logo

logo.jpg file is in presta/img/logo.jpg - so it looks good

Any ideas ?

It happens after I made SSL certification.

Answer (score 1):

You have indicated an incorrect path, simply delete `/presta/`. Based on your code, this should work:

```
<a href="{$base_dir}" title="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
    <img class="logo img-responsive" src="https://www.e-veloce.com/img/logo.jpg" alt="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{if $logo_image_width} width="{$logo_image_width}"{/if}{if $logo_image_height} height="{$logo_image_height}"{/if}/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
src="{$base_dir_ssl}img/logo.jpg"; // https://www.e-veloce.com/img/logo.jpg
src="{$base_dir_ssl}presta/img/logo.jpg"; // https://www.e-veloce.com/presta/img/logo.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. You need to do:

```
<img class="logo img-responsive" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Veloce - Chemia od nas, dla Ciebie" width="367" height="54">
```

so i cut src with https:// only to img/logo.jpg.

Problem is popular, I hope that solution will help someone in future

Comment: This way is true if you don't have any folder on your urls. if you turn on link_rewrite on prestashop, you'll have problem on any pages that has folder on url (for example: https://youDomain.ext/folder/product.html  => https://youDomain.ext/folder/img/logo.jpg is not exist)